# Retrieve content from html tag in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, uwp-xaml

I have the following html content and I need to get a code block which can get the value of the input fields by specifying it's name.
Since I am new in UWP development environment, could someone please guide me.

```
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="Hello">
```

The expected output in the string variable is Hello.
Thanks.

Note:
I tried using HTML Agility Pack and there were duplicates of sockets.dll creating build errors.

Comment: http://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: "Note: I tried using HTML Agility Pack and there were duplicates of sockets.dll creating build errors." Cannot reproduce your issue, please detail the steps.

Comment: When I add the HTML agility pack I get 2 compile errors:

1.  Payload contain two or more files with the same destination path System.net.socket.dll
2. Payload contain two or more files with the same destination path System.threading.timer.dll

Answer (score 0):

The problem with HTML Agility Pack is probably caused by NuGet, I am able to install it without problems. Follow these steps:

1. Right-click your solution, select **Manage NuGet Packages**, go to **Updates** tab and update everything to the latest stable version.
2. Right-click your solution, select **Clean**.
3. Go to **Tools** -> **NuGet Package Manager** -> **Package Manager Settings** and click the **Clear all NuGet caches** button
4. Close Visual Studio and open the folder of your project and delete the `bin` and `obj` folders.
5. Open your solution again and try to build it.